Limiting a process to only allowed to use specified network interface
I have binary program named wstunnel.
That program has no option to specify outgoing traffic. By default it will use ens3. I expect the program will use warp interface.
I'm not sure iptables can solve this, if we make ALLOW rule to warp interface exclusively for wstunnel, the process/program doesn't care whether it's exclusive for him or not.

I think it can be solved by isolating into docker or udocker for minimal version.
For another solution, luckily my binary program support --socket-so-mark option to mark packet. So for another reader, if your program support packet marking.  You can use this approach.
So, what I did:

Setup SO mark.

wstunnel server ws://10.148.0.69:2052  --socket-so-mark 1234 


Create table rule with ID 100 based on mark 1234

sudo ip rule add fwmark 1234 table 100


Add a route of table ID 100. Where warp is 172.16.0.2

sudo ip route add default dev warp table 100

I opened issue to binary program so that it can be explicitly to use specified interface for outgoing traffic: https://github.com/erebe/wstunnel/issues/285
